# Mono API and Generic Parameters

Tags: c++, mono

I'm trying to get the generic parameters of the type from a MonoClassField.
Thats my current setup

```
m_type = mono_field_get_type(_field);
m_type_class = mono_class_from_mono_type(m_type);
MonoGenericContainer* generic_class = mono_class_try_get_generic_container(m_type_class);
MonoGenericInst* generic_inst = generic_class->context.class_inst;
MonoType* underlying_type = generic_inst->type_argv[generic_args_offset];
```

And that works to a certain level, since I'm getting a MonoType of class `T`, but in the example of a `System.Nullable<bool> (bool?)` I would want a MonoType of `System.Bool`, not `T`.

Any directions on how I could read that statically? (without a instance)